# With Angular Directives, do Service subscriptions need to be unsubscribed?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Using Angular 10, I have a Directive that listens to a Service. Do I need to unsubscribe from that Observable in this scenario?

For example:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appShowFoo]'
})
export class ShowFooDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.foo') foo: boolean;

    constructor(private _fooService: FooService) {
        this._fooService.foo$.subscribe(foo => this.foo = foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always unsubscribe. Active subscriptions are what occupy memory and if not cleaned cause a memory leak, not where you use them.

Something like this will clean the subscription upon observable completion.

```js
const sub = this.observable$.subscribe(
    value =>{...}, 
    error => {...}, 
    /*onComplete*/
    () => sub.unsubscribe()
);
```

For one shot operations you may just call `toPromise()` and use `then` or `await`.